# Use MapKit to generate a route with a specific distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, mapkit

Getting a lat/long coord a specific distance away from the users current location is easy enough, but that's based on a linear line and when converted to an actual route ends up being much longer than the calculated route (obviously).

My idea was to generate a route at some point x miles away and "step back" through the steps (if that's even possible) until I get to the distance x. This approach seems pretty unreliable, and I'm certain there's got to be an easier way. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a pretty broad question there, but I would start either at the [MKDirections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKDirections) or [Google Directions AP](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)I, and work up from there.

Neither of these offer the ability to calculate a route of a desired distance unfortunately, considering it has no real practical use.